# Using fread to read in 16 byte blocks

Tags: c

I am writing some code that is supposed to read in blocks of 16 bytes at a time from an input file. I am using fread to do this however I run into problems when I get to the last few bytes of the file.

```
size_t bytesread=1;

while(bytesread > 0){

  bytesread = fread(buffer,16,1,inputfile);
  buffer[16]='\0';
  fprintf("Read in line: "%s"\n,buffer);

}
```

Say for example my text file is "This is a testfile. Here are some words".

It would print out

```
Read in line: "This is a testfi"
Read in line: "le. Here are som"
Read in line: "e words 
are som"
```

I can't figure out why it adds on the extra characters when reading in the last line. I understand that I am reading in a block of 16 bytes but how would I deal with the last block where I only want to read in the last 7 bytes?

Comment: Use the “bytesread” variable. Consult the fread documentation and examples.

Comment: Yeah - why [16] when you have ' bytesread'?

Comment: Suppose the last block is fewer than 16 bytes? Then none of it will be read and `buffer[16]='\0';` is no good. If you are concerned with bytes you should try to read 16 items each size 1. You should only read 1 item size 16 if the data makes no sense otherwise, such as a `struct`.

Comment: BTW, you should post real code (code that you've actually compiled and tested), and you should post the real output (cut and pasted from the terminal). The code you've posted won't compile, and wouldn't generate that output even if it did. See [mcve].

Answer (score 4):

`fread(buffer,16,1,inputfile);` attempts to read one block of 16 bytes. If it fails, `fread` returns zero, indicating that zero complete blocks were read.

You do not want this; you want to know how many characters were read. So use this code, which attempts to read 16 blocks of one byte each:

```
bytesread = fread(buffer, 1, 16, inputfile);
```

After this code, `bytesread` contains the number of bytes read. You can use this to put an end-of-string marker after the last byte read:

```
buffer[bytesread] = '\0';
```

Then `printf("Read in line: \"%s\"\n", buffer);` will print the bytes just read and no more.